# Passing timeout for read operation in Stackexchange.redis

Tags: timeout, stackexchange.redis

Is there any way to pass timeout for a read operation (Get,HashGetAll, etc) in StackExchange.Redis??
My code 
`var Map = await db.HashGetAllAsync("Key");`
Needs some timeout check. Is there any way to pass timeout as flags parameter, like what we do for a high priority operation

```
var map = await db.HashGetAllAsync("key", flags: CommandFlags.HighPriority);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think waiting on the task is better. So I changed my code like,

```
var mmap = db.HashGetAllAsync("key", flags: CommandFlags.HighPriority);

    if(mm.Wait(100))
    {
         if (segment_map.Result != null)
         {
               //statements...
         }
    }
```